# Test if value of preceding element is the same as current value in for each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file where the element called, identifier, can occur 1+ times. The values stored in these identifier elements can be things like file names, other local identifiers, what is called a PID (a number:number format) and a handle (http://hdl.handle.net/.... url). This information can appear in any order or the PID can be 1st or the handle or the file name; it is random. I'm interested in the PID and handle and the data has these 3 scenarios for the PID and handle within the parent element record:

1) the PID only appears once in the suite of identifier elements
2) the handle only appears once in the suite of identifier elements
3) the PID and handle appear both once in the suite of identifier elements.

In scenario 1, I want to add the prefix "http://hdl.handle.net/11134/" to the PID and put this value in the identifier element and then add an element source where I construct a url based on the PID.

In scenario 2, I want to just bring the value of the identifier field to that same identifier in a new xml file and construct a url based on this handle in a new source element.

In scenario 3, I want to either select the PID or the handle but not both. Let's say that I just want the handle and not the PID and then I do scenario 2.

When there is both a PID and a handle present, I have 2 identifiers and 2 source elements and I'm not sure how to change it so that only it only does scenario 2.

I'm new to xslt and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'v tried variations of preceding-sibling and for-each and choose but the results for scenario 3 are always 2 identifier elements and 2 source elements.

Thanks for any help.

Here's a sample of the xml:

```
<record>
<identifier>200003:93939393</identifier>
<identifier>sampleFilename.jpg</identifier>
<identifier>otherLocalidentifier</identifier>
<identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/200003:93939393</identifier>
</record>
<record>
<identifier>otherfilename.tiff</identifier>
<identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/50003:93939393</identifier>
</record>
<record>
<identifier>somelocal name</identifier>
<identifier>94949:93999393</identifier>
</record>
```

In this xml, there are other values for identifiers and the number of identifier elements are random and the PID and handle can appear in any order.

The output I want is to just have always 1 identifier and 1 source element in the new xml file:

```
<record>
<identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/200003:93939393</identifier>
<source>200003:93939393/TN</source>
</record>
<record>
<identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/50003:93939393</identifier>
<source>50003:93939393/TN</source>
</record>
<record>
<identifier>http://hdl.handle.net/11134/94949:93999393</identifier>
<source>94949:93999393/TN</source>
</record>

<xsl:template match="identifier">
<xsl:variable name="idvalue">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains(., 'http://hdl.handle.net/')">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="matches(., '^\d{5,10}[:]\d*$')">
<xsl:text>http://hdl.handle.net/11134/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise/>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$idvalue[1]"></xsl:value-of>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Lots of people will be happy to help but few to none will write code to spec for you.  You'll get the best help if you first try yourself and then ask questions about where you're stuck.  You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30133118/edit) your question to [improve it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically to add your XSLT attempt.

Comment: Could you expand on the logic by which this needs to work? It seems like one needs to start by selecting the first identifier that contains a ":" , tokenize it using "/" as the delimiter and get the last token. Is that correct? -- + Please indicate which XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: I've tried a number of solutions (preceding-sibling, nested if statements). When the PID and the handle appear in <record> I don't understand how to only do stuff on one and not the other. The problem is that the colon might appear in other values that are neither the PID or handle. I'm using xslt version 2

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't answer my question. AFAICS, the problem is **not** "*how to only do stuff on one and not the other*". That's actually trivial. The real problem is how to identify the PID substring in the containing string so it can be extracted. If other substrings can contain a colon too, then you need to provide some criteria that would apply *only* to a PID and not to the other substrings - such as containing only digits and/or minimum/maximum length of the components, etc.

Comment: @Jennifer, this is a good question! Please, see my answer for correct solutions **both** in XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 1.0. Do note that the other answer produces wrong results when its transformation is applied on the XML document from my answer.

Comment: "*the other answer produces wrong results*" No, it does not. It produces a strictly correct result **under the stated assumption**.

Comment: This is the **fate** of taking "*stated assumptions*" for granted...;

Answer (score 0):

**I. This correct XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vPat"
      select="'(^\d{5,10}:\d+$)|(^hdl.handle.net/11134/\d{5,10}:\d+$)'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record/*[matches(., $vPat)][1]">
    <identifier>
     <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'^(.*?)(\d{5,10}:\d+)$','hdl.handle.net/11134/$2')"/>
    </identifier>
    <source>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'^(.*?)(\d{5,10}:\d+)$', '$2/TN')"/>
    </source>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="record/*" priority="0"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <record>
        <identifier>other/Local/12345:67/identifier</identifier>
        <identifier>200003:93939393</identifier>
        <identifier>sampleFilename.jpg</identifier>
        <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/200003:93939393</identifier>
    </record>
    <record>
        <identifier>Some/50003:</identifier>
        <identifier>otherfilename.tiff</identifier>
        <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/50003:93939393</identifier>
    </record>
    <record>
        <identifier>somelocal name</identifier>
        <identifier>94949:93999393</identifier>
    </record>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <record>
      <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/200003:93939393</identifier>
      <source>200003:93939393/TN</source>
   </record>
   <record>
      <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/50003:93939393</identifier>
      <source>50003:93939393/TN</source>
   </record>
   <record>
      <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/94949:93999393</identifier>
      <source>94949:93999393/TN</source>
   </record>
</t>
```

---

**II. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template priority="3" match=
   "record/*[floor(substring-before(., ':')) = substring-before(., ':')
         and floor(substring-after(., ':')) = substring-after(., ':')
          ]">
    <identifier><xsl:value-of select="concat('hdl.handle.net/11134/',.)"/></identifier>
    <source><xsl:value-of select="concat(., '/TN')"/></source>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
  "record[not(*[floor(substring-before(., ':')) = substring-before(., ':')
             and floor(substring-after(., ':')) = substring-after(., ':')
                ]
             )]
             /*[starts-with(., 'hdl.handle.net/11134/')]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <source><xsl:value-of select="
    concat(substring-after(., 'hdl.handle.net/11134/'), '/TN')"/></source>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text() |identifier"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document, again produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <record>
      <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/200003:93939393</identifier>
      <source>200003:93939393/TN</source>
   </record>
   <record>
      <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/50003:93939393</identifier>
      <source>50003:93939393/TN</source>
   </record>
   <record>
      <identifier>hdl.handle.net/11134/94949:93999393</identifier>
      <source>94949:93999393/TN</source>
   </record>
</t>
```

Comment: You should state the assumptions you have made that were not given by the OP - such as "*a record will always contain one identifier containing only the PID, and/or one identifier containing the PID preceded by a known string*" and "*any two groups of digits separated by a colon are PID for this purpose*".

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Of course, I never made these assumptions!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your regex uniquely identifies a PID, I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:variable name="pid" select="(identifier/tokenize(., '/')[matches(., '^\d{5,10}[:]\d*$')])[1]"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <identifier><xsl:value-of select="concat('hdl.handle.net/11134/', $pid)"/></identifier>
        <source><xsl:value-of select="concat($pid, '/TN')"/></source>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2CE/1